# Macro to subtract multiple cells and output the results

Tags: excel, vba

I found a macro that subtracts the values in one cell in a workbook from another cell in a workbook to output the result in a final third workbook. It exists as such

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
    Dim lngDiff As Long

    On Error GoTo Err

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\FirstDataFile.xlsx")
    Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open("C:\SecondDataFile.xlsx")

    lngDiff = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value - _
              wb3.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = lngDiff

    wb3.Close savechanges:=False
    wb2.Close savechanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to modify this code that it can do this for multiple lines at once.

For example. get it to subtract wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value - _
          wb3.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value and output that result into wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value and then do the same for A2, A3 and so on so forth until about A:120000? I would also like to be able to get this done on multiples sheets on the two books that I am drawing info from. How would this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-for-loop/#What_are_Loops_and_Why_Do_You_Need_Them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a loop through a list of worksheet names, and outsource the subtraction to subroutine `InAllValuesOfColumnA` that loops through all rows of each sheet as shown below. I further recommend to use meaningful variable names instead of numbered variables (which is a bad practice and easily gets mixed up).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExampleSample()
    Dim wbResult As Workbook, wbData As Workbook, wbSubtract As Workbook
    Dim lngDiff As Long

    On Error GoTo Err

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbResult = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("C:\FirstDataFile.xlsx")
    Set wbSubtract = Workbooks.Open("C:\SecondDataFile.xlsx")

    Dim WorksheetList() As Variant
    WorksheetList = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2") 'add the worksheet names here

    Dim WsName As Variant
    For Each WsName In WorksheetList
        InAllValuesOfColumnA OfWorksheet:=wbData.Worksheets(WsName), SubtractWorksheet:=wbSubtract.Worksheets(WsName), WriteToWorksheet:=wbResult.Worksheets(WsName)
    Next WsName

    wbData.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wbSubtract.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub


Private Sub InAllValuesOfColumnA(ByVal OfWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal SubtractWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal WriteToWorksheet As Worksheet)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = OfWorksheet.Cells(OfWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow 'run from first to last row and subtract
        WriteToWorksheet.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = CLng(OfWorksheet.Cells(iRow, "A").Value - SubtractWorksheet.Cells(iRow, "A").Value)
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

---

An even faster way would be to read/write the data into arrays before/after calculation:

```
Private Sub InAllValuesOfColumnA(ByVal OfWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal SubtractWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal WriteToWorksheet As Worksheet)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = OfWorksheet.Cells(OfWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'read all into array
    Dim DataColumn() As Variant
    DataColumn = OfWorksheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value

    Dim SubtractColumn() As Variant
    SubtractColumn = SubtractWorksheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value

    Dim ResultColumn() As Variant
    ResultColumn = WriteToWorksheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value


    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(ResultColumn) To UBound(ResultColumn) 'run from first to last row and subtract
        ResultColumn(iRow) = CLng(DataColumn(iRow) - SubtractColumn(iRow))
    Next iRow

    WriteToWorksheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value = ResultColumn
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey man, Just wanted to say this worked! Thanks, I have not used the second part yet but I am trying to get that in as well.